# Finding raster with max. value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

If I have a large series of raster files (say temperature by decade) and want to find which raster file has the highest temperature. How do I do that? Cell statistics will give me the highest temperature, but not the file that contained the highest value.

How do I find the file that had that value?

Comment: Use python to iterate over a folder of rasters calling the raster properties tool keeping a record of which raster has the highest value.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Highest Position](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/highest-position.htm) tool.

> Determines on a cell-by-cell basis the position of the raster with the maximum value in a set of rasters.

[image]